# is it possible to run multiples of the same operating system one one computer at the same time?

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, vpn, operating-systems

I am attempting to run multiple systems at once one ONE computer all at the same time. Is this at all possible? my knowledge of computers and technology is limited, but to give you a little more insight i will explain the situation.
I am trying to run a single program multiple times on one computer, but the program restricts you to only being able to open it once at a time. I figured if i could split up, or partition my hard drive, than it could maybe run multiple systems at once, and maybe it would let me run one of these programs on each system. I am also trying to get each of these systems to each work from a different IP. I thought maybe setting up a VPN on each system might work after i have it all split up, but again my knowledge of this technology is very limited. If there is any other way to achieve this goal or anything close please mention it. My main goal is being able to open this program multiple times on one computer and have each running from a different IP. If this is not possible please explain why.

Comment: You could do this with multiple virtualized OS's, but it will be resource intensive. I think there are easier ways of running multiple instances of an application (even if it says it won't let you), I'm just not informed enough to help you in that regard.

Comment: No this is not possible, but you can use a virtual machine, like mantan129 suggested.

Comment: Maybe if you let us know more about this software that won't run multiple times on your computer, or what it provides you, we can think of a work-around.

Comment: As noted, virtualization is the only way. The problem is mainly that an operating system requires full use of the hardware. It can't simply share memory with another OS. Virtualization is the only way around this. VPNs and hard drive partitions have nothing to do with system resources and how a program is launched and utilized within an operating system. Out of curiosity, what program are you trying to use? If we had more details, we might be able to provide a more eloquent solution.

Comment: can you do a VM say 5 or 10 times? can you run a VPN to mask its IP? or is it just 1 extra VM?

Comment: the software isnt out yet. its a artificial intelligence-type software used for games and repetitive tasks. basically a robot that records your activity and essentially figures out how to copy it and repeat

Comment: if anyone is interested, it is called Genesis from RiD. The software is originally designed for an online game, but dont be fooled it is some pretty next level stuff if im not mistaken

Comment: a link to the forum explaining the software.
http://www.robotzindisguise.com/forum/showthread.php?23705-Development-Diary-RiD-Genesis-a-new-botting-platform

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Virtual Machine (VM, for short). A good software for this is [Oracle VM Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which is **free** and fairly easy to use. If you want commercial software, there's [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/), which offers additional features.

When you create a VM you can control its properties and hardware allocation, such as number of CPU cores available for the VM, RAM (memory) allocation, storage on disk and so on. When you power on the Virtual Machine you can install any operating system, like Linux and Windows. You can connect the VM to the internet and share files between your physical machine and the VM, and so on. Both programs are available to all major operating systems.

Here's a screenshot from Oracle VM Virual Box running Windows XP on a Windows 7 environment:
[image: Oracle VM Virtual Box running Windows XP on a Windows 7]

Comment: very helpful i will defenitly look into this

Comment: Although this is the answer to go, I miss the bit of explaination why an OS can only run once.

Comment: apparently "The problem is mainly that an operating system requires full use of the hardware. It can't simply share memory with another OS. Virtualization is the only way around this..."

Comment: @LDChip, do you mean two operating systems running side by side?

Comment: thats what im attempting to do. if the systems cant run simultaneously it is of no use to me

Comment: I'll divide my answer to two parts:
1. Technically, the physical machine and the VM run simultaneously. You can use your host OS while the VM is running.
2. You cannot run 2 operating systems side by side. The reason for that is that you have only one set of CPU, HDD, etc. If two independent programs will try to utilize the **same hardware** at the same time, with no coordination between the two, it will result with unexpected outcomes. This situation is only possible when one OS (the host) manages the other one (the VM).

Comment: Also, in my experience you can run up to two VMs with reasonable hardware allocation while keeping OK speed when using an average home PC (4GB ram, multi-core CPU should do it). If you run your programs on the VM with no GUI mode (text mode/CMD mode), it will be even faster.

Comment: also does this all trace back to one IP? the thing i am attempting to do will not work on one IP. It needs to look like different computers are running each program separately. Could running a VPN on the VM solve this?

Comment: The VM has the same IP as you, because the traffic generated by the VM is using your internet connection. VPN on the VM [should solve the issue.](http://superuser.com/questions/670152/does-vpn-connection-on-virtual-machine-bypass-host-vpn)

Comment: would it keep my host OS IP the same as it originally was and only change my VM IP? or both? sorry for so many questions. thanks for all the help

Comment: VPN on the guest machine (another term for VM, for you to know) will not affect the host IP.

Comment: If you really need a robust way to do a lot of VMs, you can get a server grade machine with virtualization capabilities and run ESXi on it. I regularly run 12-15 VMs in my lab. It isn't free, but it is effective if that is what you need. You would also be able to use DHCP to give each VM a unique IP very easily with this setup.

Comment: @Drew, If you place the virtual machine's network adapter into bridged mode (as opposed to NAT mode) then it would have a different IP address and would look like another computer was plugged into your router.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to run multiple instances of a program that only lets you have one, then a virtual machine may be overkill.  Unless you've got gobs of RAM, you won't be able to run more than a couple VM instances before you run into memory problems.

I would recommend creating multiple user accounts.  You could then do a runas under each account's credentials.  Most programs running under the context of one user cannot detect another instance of themselves running under another user's account.